# Adding total bandwidth graph to Munin

Tags: munin

I've been trying to figure this out for an hour... how to get a total bandwidth graph (showing all network traffic) in Munin? I just installed Munin, got several plugins added but what I'd really like to see is this:

http://www.schettino.us/monitor/schettino.us/BandwidthMon/totband.html

I don't want to just track apache, because it's for a game server. I've been using vnstat but I really to see long-term graphs.

A previous question was closed because of this:

[how to get a total bandwidth graph in munin](https://serverfault.com/questions/239553/how-to-get-a-total-bandwidth-graph-in-munin)

But the info here doesn't work. I've tried it already - the first example only looks at http bandwidth and it's not what I want and the second example kills my munin install as an invalid config option.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW after >2 years, the `bandwidth_` plugin on http://munin-monitoring.org/browser/munin-contrib/plugins/network/bandwidth_ should be able to do this. I'm not entirely sure whether this is what you want since the link you posted is broken.

The `bandwidth_` plugin shows a cummulative graph of the bandwidth used in e.g. a month.

I was stumbling accross this question as I cannot get my `bandwidth_` plugin to work.